# JUnit Security Test Error for Service Test of Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-security

I have to write a test function for findInContextUser based on JUnit Mock in Spring Boot but I have no idea how to write it.

How can I write findInContextUser for Junit Test?

Here are my code defined in UserService shown below.

```
public UserDto getUserDto(String username) {
        var user = findUserByUsername(username);
        return UserDto.builder()
                .id(user.getId())
                .username(user.getUsername())
                .role(user.getRole())
                .build();
    }

    public UserDto findInContextUser() {
        final Authentication authentication = Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()).orElseThrow(notFoundUser(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
        final UserDetails details = Optional.ofNullable((UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).orElseThrow(notFoundUser(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
        return getUserDto(details.getUsername());
    }

    private static Supplier<GenericException> notFoundUser(HttpStatus unauthorized) {
        return () -> GenericException.builder().httpStatus(unauthorized).errorMessage("user not found!").build();
    }
```

Here is my test class shown below.

```
@Test
    void itShouldFindInContextUser(){
        // given - precondition or setup
        User user = User.builder()
                .username("username")
                .password("password")
                .role(Role.USER)
                .build();

        UserDto expected = UserDto.builder()
                .id(user.getId())
                .username(user.getUsername())
                .role(user.getRole())
                .build();

        var roles = Stream.of(user.getRole())
                .map(x -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(x.name()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        UserDetails details = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), roles);

        Authentication authentication = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
        SecurityContext securityContext = Mockito.mock(SecurityContext.class);

        // when -  action or the behaviour that we are going test
        when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
        when(securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).thenReturn(details);

        // then - verify the output
        UserDto actual = userService.findInContextUser(); // ERROR IS HERE
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
        assertEquals(expected.getUsername(), actual.getUsername());

        verify(userService, times(1)).findInContextUser();

    }
```

Here is the error message shown below.

```
com.example.lib.exception.GenericException
Debug Part : 401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

I also added `@WithMockUser(username = "username", password = "password", roles = "USER")` but nothing changed.

Comment: Spring Security @WithMockUser annotation might help.

Comment: @ILyaCyclone I still got the same issue after using `@WithMockUser`. How can I fix it?

Comment: @ILyaCyclone I still couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution shown below.

Add **this line** shown below underneath `when` parts

```
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
```